# Evaluating this determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am asked to find the following determinant $$D = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\\ n+1 & n+2 & \cdots & 2n \\\ \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  \\\ n(n-1)+1 & n(n-1)+2 & \cdots  & n^2 \end{vmatrix} \ $$ where $n\in\mathbb N$. Any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step 1: Substract line 1 to line 2 and to line 3. 

Step 2: Line 3 is now twice line 2, hence D=0. 

Step 3: Check what happens when there is no line 3, that is, when n=1 or n=2.

Comment: As you suggested I got $D=1$ when $n=1$, $D=-2$ when $n=2$. Right?

Comment: @NancyR Yes that is correct.